# Druapl 8 login after disabling the authentification block

Tags: authentication, drupal-8

How i can login after disabling the authentificatin block in Drupal 8.

I try this :

- http://www.example.com/user/login
- http://www.example.com/?q=user
- http://www.example.com/user

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute `drush uli username`, this will generate one time login link for that user, then u can enable the authentificatin bloc.